# Permission issue while installing the Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, terminal

I am installing the node and angular on my MAC book. Node.js is installed and version of node is `v10.16.0`.

Now I am installing the angular so I tried

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

but I am getting some permission error.

```
quesBank-MacBook-Air:~ quesBank$ node -v
v10.16.0
quesBank-MacBook-Air:~ quesBank$ npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/quesBank/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR! path /Users/quesBank/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/quesBank/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/quesBank/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/Users/quesBank/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    '/Users/quesBank/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/quesBank/.npm/_logs/2019-07-24T09_14_12_078Z-debug.log
quesBank-MacBook-Air:~ quesBank$
```

Then I tried below command

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

It asks for the password then I checked `ng --version`

```
quesBank-MacBook-Air:~ quesBank$ ng --version
-bash: ng: command not found

quesBank-MacBook-Air:~ quesBank$
```

Would you help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed Node on your Mac via downloading the installer package from the Node website, this option generates permissions errors with later versions of macOS (I *think* from Sierra onwards.) They are incredibly infuriating!

If you are able to fully uninstall Node (no mean feat), you can reinstall it via Homebrew, and this automatically resolves the permissions issues.

However, as fully uninstalling Node is not particularly easy on Mac (although some helpful commenter might prove me wrong!), you can follow this guide:

https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Following this guide allows you to do global npm installs without any further issue, although the downside is that you occasionally have to run `source ~/.profile` (.profile is explained in the guide) in order to access your global Node modules.

Comment: give me some time to check

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: I tried your answer and I got like this

quesBank-MacBook-Air:~ quesBank$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
Password:
/Users/quesBank/.npm-global/bin/ng -> /Users/quesBank/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@8.1.2 postinstall /Users/quesBank/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@8.1.2
updated 1 package in 49.711s
quesBank-MacBook-Air:~ quesBank$